# How to get my overlapsphere to work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my error code :

> Assets/Scripts/PlayerDamage.cs(166,35): warning CS0219: The variable `hitCol' is assigned but its value is never used

I'm just not sure why it's not working properly. I thought I was using it in the input function under attackVKC. I should mention this is for a multiplayer game in unity.

Basically damage is getting done to the player casting the attack and not to the other players. I'm trying to get an aoe (area of effect) attack.

```
private Collider[] hitColliders;


    else if (Input.GetButton ("Special") && (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire2") && offcd == true && offccd == true)) {
        attackVKC();
        StartCoroutine("GlobalCooldown");
        StartCoroutine("GlobalCCooldown");
    }

[Client]
void attackVKC(){

   hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere (transform.position, special.rangeVKC, mask);
        {

           if (GetComponent<Collider>().tag == PLAYER_TAG)
        {
                CmdPlayerHit(GetComponent<Collider>().name, special.damageVKC);

            }

        }
    Debug.LogError (GetComponent<Collider>().name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually sloved this. I wasn't looping through the array and I didn't realise getcomponent was for the gameobject attached. So that's why it was hitting the player using the attack and not other players.